# Inject a value from javascript into a PageLink

Tags: jquery, razor, datatable

In the following jQuery DataTable code in my ASP.NET Razor Page:

```
    data: "Id", 
    fnCreatedCell: function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol)
    {
        if (oData.Id) {
            $(nTd).html("<a href='@Url.PageLink("Edit","Contact",new { id = ?? })'>Edit</a>");
        }
    }
```

How do I get the value of oData.Id (let's say it's 1) in here `{ id = ?? }`? 
It works as intended if I hardcode a 1 there, but that's only for record 1.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  instead of creating `new {id=??}` and trying to inject into that, I can use string manipulation like this:

```
    $(nTd).html('<a href="@Url.PageLink("Edit")?id=' + oData.Id + '">Edit</a>')
```

Works perfectly.